# Balut dice game Java

Tags: java, arrays, dice

I'm making a game for an extra assignment for my college and I have to create a dice game known as "balut" I'm having some issues with assigning values to an array, and having the dice values stored within this array.

I'm in week 9 of 11 of my course we've covered arrays and methods however this is a new concept for me. The goal is as follows:

```
Balut = all five dice have the same number. 
Straight =  a total of 15 Or 20.
Sixes = 1 or more sixes.
Fives = 1 or more fives.
Fours = 1 or more fours.
10 rounds. 
Total scoring of categories. 
total of scores. 
If no category is met "none" is printed.
```

I've put at least 14 hours into this and it was intended to be a 6 to 8 hour program and I still am struggling, questioning if I have the intelligence for the course and am hoping someone here can explain what I'm doing wrong or even what I should be studying.

I've tried creating a single array and assigning all dice values to this array, I run into the problem of when it comes to comparing the values I don't know how to do dice 1 == dice 2 == dice 3 etc.

I've then attempted to make 5 arrays 1 for each dice and use the compare array method which again I can only seem to get it to compare 2 arrays or variables I can't get it to compare all 5 like I'm attempting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] Dicearraytotal1 = new int[10];
    int[] Dicearraytotal2 = new int[10];
    int[] Dicearraytotal3 = new int[10];
    int[] Dicearraytotal4 = new int[10];
    int[] Dicearraytotal5 = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < Dicearraytotal1.length; i++) {
        Integer dice1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        Integer dice1val = dice1;
        Integer dice2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        Integer dice2val = dice2;
        Integer dice3 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        Integer dice3val = dice3;
        Integer dice4 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        Integer dice4val = dice4;
        Integer dice5 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        Integer dice5val = dice5;
        Dicearraytotal1[i] = (dice1val);
        Dicearraytotal2[i] = (dice2val);
        Dicearraytotal3[i] = (dice3val);
        Dicearraytotal4[i] = (dice4val);
        Dicearraytotal5[i] = (dice5val);
    Integer total = (dice1val+dice2val+dice3val+dice4val+dice5val);

        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated1: " + Arrays.toString(Dicearraytotal1));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated2: " + Arrays.toString(Dicearraytotal2));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated3: " + Arrays.toString(Dicearraytotal3));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated4: " + Arrays.toString(Dicearraytotal4));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated5: " + Arrays.toString(Dicearraytotal5));
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Comment: Any reason you are using `Integer` instead of `int` for the dice values?

Comment: A) allow for a short break from your curriculum and study java naming conventions. only class names go UpperCammelCase, variable and field names go camelCase. Always B) you are writing quite a bit of nonsensical code. There is zero sense in using **two** temp variables within your first loop. Simply assign `Dicearraytotal1[i] = (int) Math.random(....)` Dont write code that doesnt need to be written. Look what you want (get a value into each array), and then do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an end bracket to stop the `for` loop, so I assume you were attempting to print the arrays each iteration of the loop.  I cleaned up your code a lot and you should take note on some of the changes in order to organize your code better which will make it easier to understand.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] diceArrayTotal1 = new int[10];
    int[] diceArrayTotal2 = new int[10];
    int[] diceArrayTotal3 = new int[10];
    int[] diceArrayTotal4 = new int[10];
    int[] diceArrayTotal5 = new int[10];
    int[] totals = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < diceArrayTotal1.length; i++) {
        diceArrayTotal1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        diceArrayTotal2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        diceArrayTotal3[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        diceArrayTotal4[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        diceArrayTotal5[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        totals[i] = (diceArrayTotal1[i] + diceArrayTotal2[i] + diceArrayTotal3[i] + diceArrayTotal4[i] + diceArrayTotal5[i]);
    }
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated1: " + Arrays.toString(diceArrayTotal1));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated2: " + Arrays.toString(diceArrayTotal2));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated3: " + Arrays.toString(diceArrayTotal3));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated4: " + Arrays.toString(diceArrayTotal4));
        System.out.println("Total Of Numbers Generated5: " + Arrays.toString(diceArrayTotal5));
        System.out.println("Totals: " + Arrays.toString(totals));
}
```

Additionally I added a `totals` array that keeps the total for each index instead of printing it every loop like you were doing.  You did not add your compare code, so I cannot assist you with that.  Let me know if you need any clarification on any changes.  I ran this code and it successfully generated the arrays you need and the totals.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate it and I am taking notes I can see the changes you've made to the array totals I'm yet to sort out the comparison code. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] results = new int[6]; // This array will hold the number of time each dice was rolled, so for example results[0] is how many 1 s you have results[5] is how many 6 you have
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   // roll the dice 5 times
        results[random.nextInt(6)]++;   //increase the counter of the appropriate value
    }

    boolean balut = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number of " + (i+1) + ": " + results[i]);
        if (results[i] == 5) {
            balut = true;
        }
    }

    if (balut) {
        System.out.println("Balut!");
    }
}
```

Here I implemented only the check for the Balut, but the main point is how I am couting the dices results. Hope it helps.